# How to create MySQL user with limited privileges?

Tags: mysql

I would like to create a user called `webapp` that can access a database called `webdb` with the following privileges

```
Select, Insert, Update, Delete, Create, Drop, References, Index, Alter, Lock_Tables
```

I created the database like so

```
mysql -u root -p -e 'create database webdb'
```

How is such a user created from the commandline?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this:

```
CREATE USER 'new_user'@'host_name' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, ALTER, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, LOCK TABLES, REFERENCES
  ON webdb.* TO 'new_user'@'host_name';
```

Second statement will grant privileges on `webdb` database.

Comment: In this case, what will be password for user 'new_user'@'host_name'?

Comment: In this case password is not specified, so you can connenct without password. Anyway, you may check password existence using `SELECT * FROM mysql.user` query.